# Android support library NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-support-library, viewpagerindicator

I have a problem with use of ViewPagerIndicator but i think the problem is the use of support library android. When i start a new activity in my code i have an NullPointerException. That is the code:

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // FULLSCREEN
    /*requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    */
    setContentView(R.layout.level);
   try{
    mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    mIndicator.setViewPager(mPager);

   }
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Workaround to avoid NPE from support library bug:

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

and the log trace is:

```
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225): Process: es.uam.eps.dadm.mark, PID: 30225
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:481)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at es.uam.eps.dadm.mark.Level.onSaveInstanceState(Level.java:54)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1153)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1223)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3175)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3234)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1223)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
03-21 17:34:39.694: E/AndroidRuntime(30225):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Your stack trace shows that you are crashing in `onSaveInstanceState()` of a `Level` class, which is not in the source code that you have in your question.

Comment: Because in this method i have only super.onSaveInstanceState() but remove this i have the same exception! but i have edit with the method!

Comment: Is there any chance that your `FragmentAdapter` is returning `null` for some page? I cannot see anything in [the source to `FragmentManagerImpl`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java) that would trigger a local `NullPointerException` in `saveFragmentBasicState()`. Beyond that, make sure that you are on the latest edition of `support-v4` or `support-v13` (whichever one you are using).

Comment: yes I update the library [meta]support-v4 with sdk manager and i copy them into lib folder of [meta]viewpagerIndicator but the result is the same!

Comment: Are you using right layout in your  setContentView ?